# Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.hbnks.mongodb.net

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to connect my mongoose with my MongoDB Atlas Cluster. It currently has no database or anything but whenever I try:

const connectDB = async () => {

try {
await mongoose.connect(dbURL, {

```
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,

});

console.log("MONGODB: Default Connection Established");
```

} catch (error) {

```
console.log(error);
process.exit(1);
```

}
};

I get this message:

Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.hbnks.mongodb.net

```
at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) {
```

errno: undefined,
code: 'ETIMEOUT',
syscall: 'queryTxt',
hostname: 'cluster0.hbnks.mongodb.net'
}

Comment: Format the post correctly and include the rest of the connect string removing passwords

Comment: Did you `whitelist` your IP at your MongoDB Atlas account? Or you can set your whitelist to `0.0.0.0/0` to allow all IPs.

Comment: I changed MongoDB and it's work.